# Workaround to WPF Menu Item Icon Behaviour in Windows 8

Tags: wpf, windows-8

I have a menu in my WPF application that uses PNG images for icons. These images are stored as resources in a separate DLL. In older versions of Windows the icons (which are 48x48 pixels) displayed correctly, shrinking to the size of the container.

In Windows 8, the icons behave differently.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
<MenuItem Header="Promotions" x:Name="mnuPromotions" Style="{StaticResource styMenuItem}">
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Image Source="{StaticResource icnPromotion_48}" Style="{StaticResource styMenuIcon}" />
    </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
<MenuItem Header="Catalogues" x:Name="mnuCatalogues" Style="{StaticResource styMenuItem}">
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Image Source="{StaticResource icnCatalogue_48}" Style="{StaticResource styMenuIcon}" />
    </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem Header="Customer Price Lists" x:Name="mnuCustomerPriceLists">
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Image Source="{StaticResource icnCashCustomer_48}" Style="{StaticResource styMenuIcon}" />
    </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

Here is the style of the menu item

```
<Style x:Key="styMenuItem" TargetType="MenuItem">
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000" />
  <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="22" />
  <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
  <Setter Property="Background">
    <Setter.Value>
      <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#AA9D9D9D" />
        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#AACFCDBE" />
      </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

And here is the style of the Icon

```
<Style x:Key="styMenuIcon" TargetType="Image">
  <Setter Property="Width" Value="20" />
  <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
  <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
  <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
  <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
</Style>
```

This is what the menu looks like in older versions of Windows:
[image: Menu in Windows XP to Windows 7]

And this is that the menu looks like in Windows 8
[image: Menu in Windows 8]

If you look closely, the icons are centred and cropped in Win8 while they fit inside the container in the older versions of Windows.

Does anybody know why this behaviour changes and if there is a simple workaround for this change in behaviour so that the menu is fully compatible with all versions of Windows from XP to 8?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this behaviour is a known bug, that (as usual) Microsof does not want to fix:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/767328/menuitem-icon-wont-stretch-when-changing-size-in-windows-8

There are two workarounds posted, the simple one is adjusting the image height to the menu item height per XAML:

```
<MenuItem x:Name="ctxMenuName" Header="Open Existing">
  <MenuItem.Icon>
     <Image Source="/MyApp;component/Images/folder_with_file.png"
                 Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=ctxMenuName}"
                 Width="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=ctxMenuName}" />
  </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 1):

Having run into this upgrading an existing WPF application to support Windows 10. Here is a workaround by inheriting from MenuItem. This will work with other content as well as Images.

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace MenuItemDemo
{
    public class MenuItemEx : MenuItem
    {
        public MenuItemEx()
        {
            base.Loaded += FrameworkElement_OnLoaded;
        }

        private void FrameworkElement_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var child = Icon as FrameworkElement;
            if (child == null)
                return;

            var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child) as ContentPresenter;
            if (parent == null)
                return;

            parent.Width = child.Width;
            parent.Height = child.Height;
        }
    }
}
```

Then to use it reference `xmlns:menuitem="clr-namespace:MenuItemDemo"` in the xaml, then change `<MenuItem>` to `<menuitem:MenuItemEx>`

An Example window using this

```
<Window x:Class="MenuItemDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:menuitem="clr-namespace:MenuItemDemo"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">    
        <DockPanel>
            <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <menuitem:MenuItemEx>
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Label>Text asdfasdf</Label>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </menuitem:MenuItemEx>  
            </Menu>
            <Grid></Grid>
        </DockPanel>     
</Window>
```